# Why Vue regular slots also available in this.$scopedSlots?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Please see this minimum example

### Test.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="this_is_not_scoped_slots"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script >
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    console.log(Object.keys(this.$scopedSlots));
  }
});
</script>
```

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <Test>
    <template #this_is_not_scoped_slots>But it shows in this.$scopedSlots</template>
  </Test>
</template>

<script>
import Test from "./Test.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Test
  }
};
</script>
```

In the above example, this console will log out `["this_is_not_scoped_slots"]`.

Why is this happening?

There are two properties in Vue instance

1. `this.$slots`
2. `this.$scopedSlots`

These two act really differently:

1. If you use `v-slot:my_scope_name="{ someValue }"`, then `my_scope_name` won't show up in `this.$slots`
2. However, no matter what you define, your named slots will always show up in `this.$scopedSlots`

Why is this happening?

I'm building a library, I want to conditional rendering if the user has provided named slots or not, should I always use `this.$scopedSlots` to detect those things?

Comment: I believe the new slot syntax was implemented this way to allow for easier migration to Vue 3. See https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0006-slots-unification.md#adoption-strategy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [official API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots) :

> 1. ....
> 2. All `$slots` are now also exposed on `$scopedSlots` as functions. If you work with render functions, it is now recommended to always access slots via `$scopedSlots`, whether they currently use a scope or not. This will not only make future refactors to add a scope simpler, but also ease your eventual migration to Vue 3, where all slots will be functions.